# how to change button icon only if time in json response is updated?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uikit

I have to change a button icon only if the time in response changes. So I created a timer function which hits api every 30 seconds and reloads table. Here is the code:

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    var refreshed = false
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        table.dataSource = self
        table.delegate = self
        
        self.getPosts()
        timer =  Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 30.0, repeats: true) { (timer) in
            self.refreshed = true
            self.getPosts()
        }
        
    }

    //TableView Datasource
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
      let data = posts[indexPath.row]
        
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HomeTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeTableViewCell
        
      let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ" // Pass any format here you want according to your date response
            let convDate = dateFormatter.date(from: data.postUpdatedAt ?? "")
            
        if refreshed == false {
            cell.timeBeforeRefreshInterval = convDate
        }
        else {
            cell.timeAfterRefreshInterval = convDate
            if cell.timeAfterRefreshInterval == cell.timeBeforeRefreshInterval {
                cell.button.setImage(UIImage(named: "1"), for: .normal)
            }
            else {
                cell.button.setImage(UIImage(named: "2"), for: .normal)
                cell.timeBeforeRefreshInterval = cell.timeAfterRefreshInterval
                refreshed = false
            }
        }        

      return cell
        
    }

}

class HomeTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    var timeBeforeRefreshInterval : Date?
    var timeAfterRefreshInterval : Date?
    
}
```

First I created variable to store date response in `HomeViewController` but it will always store the response of last cell created so I added those variables in `HomeTableVIewCell`. However its still not working. Is there any better logic to compare times of post and update your cell according to that? All I wanna do is compare time, if someone posts something in group, time gets updated and I need to change button icon to show someone has posted something new.

Comment: Seems you need to add these two variable (var timeBeforeRefreshInterval : Date?
    var timeAfterRefreshInterval : Date?) in your response model class. And assign/update/retrive value of these two variables from your response model class.

Comment: im confused here. I already have "postUpdatedAt" in model class for time. If I add those variables in response model class what values will I assign to them? I can only assign postUpdatedValue

Comment: Idont realy understand what you are trying to here, but I think you should create a new data type where you store the response plus a var that indicate if date did change from last response or not, so create a struct that will hold the response and add a var like `var dateDidChange: Bool` equal something like to currentData.date != response.date.
-- Show some more code so we help faster

Comment: @Siempay I just want to change 1 button icon in cells. The thing is this button is inside post created by a Store owner who also has a chat group. When chat will be active the button will have different icon on every post created by store owner. Imagine Instagram post with like button, but the like button will change icon if someone texts in group & every post by store owner will have like button changed

Comment: That's instagram example, here I have chat icon which I want to change based on active chat. I have time in response for latest message, so using that I want to change chat icon to green for every post he has created.

Comment: You need to show all your code with how you tried to do it and select where is the problem exactly

Comment: @simepay sorry for late reply but apparently using your method worked. Created a Boolean variable (isUpadted) in my data model and as im using socket so I can just set its value equals to true whenever there is new message and reload table